How to create a generic Web API method
For example, the following method does not work whether the method is generic or the controller is generic:
public BaseOutput GetByNameOrId<T>(int id, string name) 
       where T : CommonEntity<T>, new()
{
    BaseOutput output = new BaseOutput();

    using (var repository = Db.GetRepository<T>())
    {
        output.Result = repository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name || x.Id == id);
    }

    return output;
}

I tried to use a method like this but don't know how to convert className to T:
public BaseOutput GetByNameOrId(string className, int id, string name)
{
    BaseOutput output = new BaseOutput();

    // How to convert className to T ?
    using (var repository = Db.GetRepository<T>())
    {
        output.Result = repository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name || x.Id == id);
    }

    return output;
}

I succeeded in the following way, but it was too troublesome, because there may be other methods that need to use generics later.
public BaseOutput GetByNameOrId(string className, int id, string name)
{
    BaseOutput output = new BaseOutput();

    // 获取类的 Type 对象
    Type targetType = Type.GetType($"MCS.Object.{className},MCS.Object");

    if (targetType != null)
    {
        var v = typeof(Db).GetMethods().Where(x => x.Name == "GetRepository" && x.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1 && x.GetParameters().Length == 1).ToList();
        MethodInfo GetRepository = typeof(Db).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "GetRepository" && x.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1 && x.GetParameters().Length == 1).MakeGenericMethod(targetType);
        var repository = GetRepository.Invoke(null, new object[] { default });
        MethodInfo FirstOrDefault = repository.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "FirstOrDefault" && x.GetParameters().Length == 2);
        // 创建动态表达式
        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(targetType, "x");
        Expression idComparison = Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(Expression.Convert(param, targetType), "Id"),
            Expression.Constant(id));
        Expression nameComparison = Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(Expression.Convert(param, targetType), "Name"),
            Expression.Constant(name));
        Expression orExpression = Expression.OrElse(idComparison, nameComparison);
        var filter = Expression.Lambda(orExpression, param);

        output.Result = FirstOrDefault.Invoke(repository, new object[] { filter, default });
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Type {className} not found.");
    }

    return output;
}

I hope there is a way to convert classname to T for generics
